# A bound on the first deviation of a local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Assume $R$ is a local ring and $R=Q/I$ with $Q$ regular. Let $\varepsilon_1(R)$ be its first deviation (the dimension as a vectorspace of the first Koszul homology). How can I prove that the first deviation is less or equal to the minimum number of generators of $I$? And that equality holds if and only if $I\subset m^2$ where $m$ is the maximal ideal of $Q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Use Theorem 2.3.2(b) from Bruns and Herzog.